# Setting state inside event handler which is inside state properties

Tags: reactjs, events, state

I've got a problem updating a state from an event which is inside this state. I mean I've got a dynamic form and this one must have an event inside their properties. I coded a small component with my problem, the code is in the url https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4wsib

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code to your question so we can more easily see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're storing a component with a click handler in the state.
Generally, you should store only the minimal data needed in the state.
It also make your logic easier to follow as you don't need to synchronize component in your state.
When using React, you should describe what your UI should look like according to the state:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vv3qw

```
import React from "react";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import Visibility from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";

export default function IconButtons() {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState({
    age: 25,
    isTall: false,
    name: "Ana"
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{person.isTall ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</span>
      <IconButton
        onClick={() => {
          setPerson({
            ...person,
            isTall: !person.isTall
          });
        }}
      >
        {person.isTall ? <DeleteIcon /> : <Visibility />}
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Komo what I really need to do is the event has to be inside the state because I'm building a dynamic form , the code above is just a short example.